# Topologies on spaces of distributions and test functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Following the notation of Schwartz, we denote $\mathcal{D}$ the space of compactly supported complex-valued smooth functions on $X$ equipped with the topology defined by the following convergence condition: a sequence of functions $\{f_i\}$ is said to converge to $f$ in $\mathcal{D}$ if (1) there exists a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $\text{Supp} f_i\subset K$ and (2) for each multi-index $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}_+^n$, $\|f-f_i\|_{K,\alpha}\rightarrow 0$ where 
$$
\|f\|_{K,\alpha}:=\sup_{x\in K}|\partial_\alpha f(x)|.
$$
On the other hand we have the space of complex-valued smooth functions on $X$ equipped with the topology generated by the seminorms
$$
\|f\|_{K,k}=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\|f\|_{K,\alpha}, \quad \quad \text{$K$ compact in $X$},
$$
which we denote as $\mathcal{E}$. In between $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ as sets we also have the space of Schwartz functions $\mathcal{S}$ which has its own standard topology generated by its own set of seminorms.

I know that all three spaces $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ are locally convex topological vector spaces. If we take the topological dual of each of them we get the space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'$, the space of tempered distributions $\mathcal{S}'$, and the space of distributions with compact supports $\mathcal{E}'$, each of which is equipped with its weak-$*$ topology respectively. As sets, we have the following injective linear maps
$$
\mathcal{D}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{S}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{E}, \quad \quad \mathcal{E}'\hookrightarrow \mathcal{S}' \hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}', \quad \quad \mathcal{D}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{E}' \quad \quad \mathcal{S}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{S}',\quad \quad \mathcal{E}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}'
$$
My question is, among these maps, which are continuous with respect to the topologies of the spaces, and which have dense image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are all continuous with dense images. See e.g. Trèves, *Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels*, [p. 272](https://books.google.com/books?id=kClvQ1qk9r8C&pg=PA272), Theorem 28.2, [p. 301](https://books.google.com/books?id=kClvQ1qk9r8C&pg=PA301), and Remark 28.3, [p. 303](https://books.google.com/books?id=kClvQ1qk9r8C&pg=PA303).

Comment: Yes, in particular one might first show that the test functions are dense in all of them, which gives other density assertions as corollaries, if one wants.